# SSRS i have a column arrival date and i need to get records that arrived 5 months and before

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, expression, fetchxml

i have tried the expression below, but it simply shows #error

```
=DateDiff("M", Format(CDate(Fields!arrivaldate.Value), "dd/MM/yyyy"), Format(Today(), "dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the formatting and it should work fine

```
=DateDiff("M", CDate(Fields!arrivaldate.Value), Today())
```

But you say you want data from 5 months ago.. this expression will only tell you how many months between arrivaldate and Today. This does not "filter" any data as such

Comment: how would i go about filtering using the date?, i was thinking of adding a calculated field with months then i lookup from that.

Comment: You can use this expression to derive a column and then add a parameter referencing this column as a filter..